# symfony toolbar missing on login

Tags: php, symfony

I went through the symfony blog tutorial at http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/index.html and wanted to extend it to require authentication.  I loosely followed http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html, created a new Bundle (I want to extract this out to a common area later) and things were working fine.  The only problem is that on the login page, it does not show the symfony toolbar (it does everywhere else), but the rest of the page displays as I expect.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

My login.html.twig:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Please Login{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% if error %}
        <div class="error-message">{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">E-mail address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}"/>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"/>

        {#
            If you want to control the URL the user
            is redirected to on success (more details below)
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
        #}

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

My ::base.html.twig:

```
<!-- app/Resources/views/base.html.twig -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"
    ; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}symblog{% endblock %} - symblog</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Irish+Grover' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=La+Belle+Aurore' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="{{ asset('css/screen.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    {% endblock %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}"/>
</head>
<body>

<section id="wrapper">
    <header id="header">
        <div class="top">
            {% block navigation %}
                <nav>
                    <ul class="navigation">
                        <li><a href="{{ path('BloggerBlogBundle_homepage') }}">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ path('BloggerBlogBundle_about') }}">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ path('BloggerBlogBundle_contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
                        {% if app.user %}
                            <li><a href="{{ path('logout') }}">Logout {{ app.user.username }}</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <h2>{% block blog_title %}<a href="{{ path('BloggerBlogBundle_homepage') }}">symblog</a>{% endblock %}</h2>

        <h3>{% block blog_tagline %}<a href="{{ path('BloggerBlogBundle_homepage') }}">creating a blog in
                Symfony2</a>{% endblock %}</h3>
    </header>

    <section class="main-col">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </section>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
    </aside>

    <div id="footer">
        {% block footer %}
            Symfony2 blog tutorial - created by <a href="https://github.com/dsyph3r">dsyph3r</a>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</section>

{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The scroll bar won't show unless a complete html page is generated.  Do a control-u on your browser.  I expect you will see some html then probably an error message or something cut off.  Which in turn will hopefully pin point the problem.

Comment: Nothing is being cut off.  I've heard that it's because the toolbar isn't setup properly under the access, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that.  Here's my security.yml:

Answer (score 1):

Edited:  I found the answer... look under the access_control.

Nothing is being cut off.  I've heard that it's because the toolbar isn't setup properly under the access, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that.  Here's my security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Database\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:          sha1
            encode_as_base64:   false
            iterations:         1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: DatabaseUserBundle:User, property: email }

    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            anonymous:  ~
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous:  ~
            form_login:
                login_path:                     login
                check_path:                     login_check
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path:            /
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: /_wdt/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }  ### These 2 lines needed
        - { path: /_profiler/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }### These 2 lines needed
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Ok, I found the answer on http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=37865&p=125808.  The access_control needs:

    access_control:
        - { path: /_wdt/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /_profiler/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }